# Label on boundary of region plot

Tags: plotting, regions, legending, labeling

Consider this plot

```
RegionPlot[{n + k > 6}, {n, 0, 4}, {k, 0, 15}, BoundaryStyle -> None]
```

I want to add a label on the boundary like in the picture. How can I do that?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
nmax = 4; kmax = 15;
RegionPlot[{n + k > 6}, {n, 0, nmax}, {k, 0, kmax}, BoundaryStyle -> None,
  Epilog -> Text[Style["label here", 16, Bold], {1, 5.5}, Left, {kmax, - nmax}]]
```

[image]

Comment: What Mathematica version and OS are you using? With v11.3 on my Mac the label isn't displayed.

Comment: @BobHanlon, I am using version 11.3 (windows 10/64).

Comment: @kglr with version 11.2 the label is not displayed

Answer (score 6):

Here's how:

```
p1 = RegionPlot[{n + k > 6}, {n, 0, 4}, {k, 0, 15}, BoundaryStyle->None];
p2 = Rotate[Graphics[Text[Style["label here", FontSize->20,Background-> Transparent, Black, Bold],Scaled[{1/4, 6.5/15}]]], -ArcTan[4/15]];
Overlay[{p1, p2}]
```

[image]